# Using react-native-tab-view with react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-navigation

I'm using [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view) as my main app container in which I have different components and nested tabs as well. However I wanted to use [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) for navigation.  I currently have the setup like so:

```
  <Router>
    <Scene key='root'>
      <Scene hideNavBar  key='home' component={ReactNativeTabViewContainer}
       tabs ={true} initial={true} />
    </Scene>
  </Router>
```

But Right now the react-native-router-flux only sees a single route. How can I track the nav changes inside the React-native-tab-view and add those nav state to the main route state stored in redux.

Comment: hi @jasan, I am a contributor in the project and I am trying to answer the questions related to `react-native-router-flux` that are unanswered over here. Sorry to only come here now - but have you found a solution for this?